# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY : [NetworkId]

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, contentdocument, contentversion, contentdocumentlink

I've written a simple trigger to enforce our Community users not to delete files. Currently, I'm facing an issue in getting test coverage for deployment.

**Trigger**

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (before delete) {
    if(trigger.isBefore){
        if(trigger.isDelete){
            ContentDocumentTriggerHelper helper = new ContentDocumentTriggerHelper();
            helper.preventFilesDeletion(Trigger.Old);
        }
    }
}
```

**Helper Class**

```
public class ContentDocumentTriggerHelper {
    public void preventFilesDeletion(List<ContentDocument> files){
        // Check whether logged in user is a Portal user
        User usr = [Select Id,Name,IsPortalEnabled from User where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
        //If it is portal user, trigger a validation saying - Attachments cannot be deleted
        if(usr.IsPortalEnabled){
            for(ContentDocument attmt: files){
                attmt.addError('Attachment cannot be deleted');
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class ContentDocumentTriggerHelperTest {

    static testMethod void ContentDocumentTest(){        
        user usr = [SELECT ContactId,Id,IsActive,IsPortalEnabled,contact.accountid FROM User WHERE IsActive = true AND IsPortalEnabled = true AND Usertype !='PowerPartner' LIMIT 1];
        
            system.runAs(usr){
                ContentVersion content = new ContentVersion(); 
                content.Title ='Header_Picture1'; 
                content.PathOnClient ='/' + content.Title + '.jpg'; 
                Blob bodyBlob = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test ContentVersion Body'); 
                content.VersionData=bodyBlob; 
                content.origin = 'H';
                insert content;

                // Test insert
                List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];
                System.assertEquals(documents.size(), 1);
                // Test delete
                delete documents;
            }          
    }
}
```

This test class fails with this exception:

**System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY,
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.: [NetworkId]**

What I've tried so far:

1. Tried removing system.runas(): Test class passes, but gives only 60%
   coverage, it didn't pass through at if(usr.IsPortalEnabled).
2. Tried setting contentVersion Owner - Getting this exception : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_STATUS, Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.: [OwnerId]
3. Tried setting FirstPublishLocationId as stated [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216150/issue-setting-contentversion-owner), getting this exception: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, You must specify a FirstPublishLocation where you have publish permission.: [FirstPublishLocationId]

Is there any other approach, where I get through this? I think my question is a duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298175/are-contentversion-unit-tests-impossible-using-a-community-user). Still, I've initiated a new conversation to see is there any solution?

Appreciate all your help!

Comment: Could you not simply set the usr as the owner of the data you create in this test?

Comment: Hi @PhilW I've tried that, but no success. 

1. When I set OwnerId I'm getting: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_STATUS, Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.: [OwnerId]
2. When I set FirstPublishLocationId I'm getting: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_STATUS, Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.: [OwnerId]

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to add these details as they are quite pertinent.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @PhilW

Comment: Do you have more than one community as the NetworkId is the community id?

Comment: Hi @DaveHumm Yes, we have four communities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar issue and this workaround helped me:

```
Id networkId = [SELECT Id FROM Network LIMIT 1].Id;

    System.runAs(portalUser) {
        
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Test',
            PathOnClient = 'Test.jpg',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content Data'),
            IsMajorVersion = true,
            NetworkId = networkId
        );
        insert contentVersion;
}
```

So I just specified NetworkId in my test ContentVersion record.

Comment: This fixes the problem for me too. Confusing results at first from a unit test as I had `Network.getNetworkId()` to find the network Id but that seems to always return null in unit tests, hence the query approach is needed for unit tests.

Comment: Perfect! This saved me so much time, I could not figure out what was going on.